# Two Different Namespaces but same java package

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

My usecase in my projects is, I have two different xsd's with
A.xsd and A'.xsd where A' is superset of all the elements of A along with an additional element type defined in A' named SuppDataType.

We have single codebase and depending on instance type parse upstream messages fwhich belong to A/A' xsd.

Now since the package elements are the same barring the extra additional element type in A'. How can I manage via JAXB to compile messages from either xsd's in our single codebase?

Comment: If A' is a superset, just use that only.

Comment: I can't..they are two different instances of the application. One instance should process message from A.xsd and the other instance should process messages from A'.xsd.  I can switch off namespace aware to ignore namespaces while making A'.xsd as the default xsd from which the jaxb classes are generated

Comment: If they are two different instance of the application, and the XML is from two different namespaces, then they are entirely separate and I've no clue what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: the codeline is a single codeline which should load either xsd's @ compile time which i know how to do or runtime for which i believe i need to switch off namespace.